# upate the price as like quantity

Tags: price, controllers, multi-vendor

we are using the following code to update the QUANTITY. I want to do the same for PRICE also

```
 <span id="valueqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?></span>
  <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "qty" value = "<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>


  <!-- aki 2 -->
<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>  
<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
    <br/>
    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
        <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
    </button>

    <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
    </button>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
        function validateNumbers(e) {
            //var key = '#keyinput_'+ product_id;
            //var e = jQuery(key);

            if (jQuery.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && ( e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true ) ) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();

        function hideReset(product_id) {
            /*
            var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(editLink).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
            */
            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;
            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
            $wk_jq(editLink).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
        }
         function showField(product_id)
        {
            /*
            var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
            */
            var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }
        function updateField(product_id)
        {
            var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
        var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

            $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
            hideReset(product_id);

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, qty: $qty},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);


                    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);

                    $wk_jq(qtyId).setValue($qty);



                }
            });
        }
```

controller file

```
public function updateFieldAction(){
    $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));

    $stockItem->save();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

}

what code needs to be changed to work for price....

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: @JulienLachal what i need to be done to update the price as like quantity

Comment: Did you just copy/paste your question? Because it makes no sense.

Comment: @JulienLachal i updated the different code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price is part of the product object rather than the stock item object. Therefore you need to take a different approach, either loading the products, updating their price values and saving them OR...

... using Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($product, array($price stuff)...).

Given this situation you may want to use Magento's import methods to import prices.